# Crash when dismissing UIActionSheet

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios7, uiactionsheet

I am facing a mysterious crash issue when running our app (64 bit complaint) inside another app. The crash happens within `UIKit` after `UIActionSheet` is dismissed.

Below is the sequence of actions I am performing:

1. Tap on the action sheet button on right side of navigation bar.
2. Tap on some action makes a server call.
3. Tap on the action sheet button again and then tap on Edit button to bring the table in edit mode.
4. Table comes in Edit mode but application crashes.

## Console Logs:

`2014-07-14 14:26:57.404 AppleEasyPay[677:60b] -[__NSCFType _canBecomeKeyWindow]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15c6abb70`

[image]

```
- (void)showDeleteRequestConfirmation:(id)iSender {
      self.actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] init];
      self.actionSheet.destructiveButtonIndex = 0;
      self.actionSheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent;
      [self.actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:MyLocalized(kDeleteButtonKey)];
      [self.actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:MyLocalized(kCancelButtonKey)];
      self.actionSheet.title = MyLocalized(kDeleteConfirmationMessageKey);
      self.actionSheet.tag = kDeleteConfirmationActionSheet;
      self.actionSheet.delegate = self;
      [self.actionSheet showInView:self.tableView];
}


- (void)showCompleteRequestConfirmaton:(id)iSender {
    if (self.totalQuantityScanned < self.totalQuantityToBeScanned) {
        self.actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] init];
            self.actionSheet.cancelButtonIndex = 1;
            [self.actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:MyLocalized(kCompleteButtonKey)];
            [self.actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:MyLocalized(kCancelButtonKey)];
            self.actionSheet.title = MyLocalized(kCompleteRequestMessageKey);
            self.actionSheet.tag = kCompleteConfirmationActionSheet;
            self.actionSheet.delegate = self;
            [self.actionSheet showInView:self.tableView];
    } else {
        [self completeRequest:iSender];
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "running our app inside another app"?

Comment: This sort of crash indicates that an object has been deallocated and your reference is invalid.  Try enabling Zombies

Comment: Enabling subviews will definitely help in locating the issue? Are you accessing subviews of action sheet anyway??

Comment: Issue was mysteriously something else. I was presenting an alert view in between 2 action sheets. See my answer below on how I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

It was a mysteriously weird issue. I just put a strong property for my UIAlerView which I was showing on tap on my first action sheet and put that in the header file and it worked. Putting the property in the extension was crashing it.